# Combining Elements Within a List to Form a New List

Tags: python, list

I am not sure of the technical terminology for what I am trying to do, but this is the gist of it. I have the following list:

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I want to create a new list y where `len(y) = 2 ** len(x)` such that:

```
y = ['∅', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a,b', 'a,c', 'b,c', 'a,b,c']
```

I am unsure of what operations to use when looping through x to create the desired list y.

Comment: You want to iterate over the subsets, so use `itertools`

Comment: what does first element `'∅'` mean in your desired list ?

Comment: @Anonymous that is common mathematical notation for the empty set

Answer (score 1):

Although this is much less efficient than itertools, if you are not allowed to use libraries, you could make a recursive function to produce the power-set and assemble the strings using join() in a list comprehension:

```
def powerSet(L):
    return [[]] if not L else [c for p in powerSet(L[1:]) for c in (p,L[:1]+p)]

x = ['a','b','c']
y = [",".join(s) or "ø" for s in powerSet(x)]

print(y)
['ø', 'a', 'b', 'a,b', 'c', 'a,c', 'b,c', 'a,b,c']
```

You can also do this directly in an iterative function that extends all previous combinations with each letter in the list:

```
def allCombos(L):
    result = [""]
    for c in L:
        result.extend([f"{r},{c}" if r else c for r in result])
    result[0] = "ø"
    return result

print(allCombos(x))
['ø', 'a', 'b', 'a,b', 'c', 'a,c', 'b,c', 'a,b,c']
```